# Why doesn't ampersand (&) work in string replacement without being escaped?

Tags: bash, scripting, string

The following script is really simple, and replaces `&amp;` with `&`:

```bash
string="Foo &amp; Bar"
echo "${string//&amp;/&}";
```

But the script does nothing. There are no error messages, and doesn't replace anything:

```
Foo &amp; Bar
```

I eventually found the solution, you need to escape the ampersand in the replacement section:

```bash
string="Foo &amp; Bar"
echo "${string//&amp;/\&}";
```

What I haven't figured out is **why**? Why doesn't the script work as expected? Why does only the last ampersand need to be escaped and not the first one (i.e. `${string//\&amp;/\&}`).

Does this mean the ampersand has a special meaning or use in string replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, [`&` stands for the matched pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> If the `patsub_replacement` shell option is enabled using `shopt`, any unquoted instances of ‘`&`’ in *string* are replaced with the matching portion of *pattern*. This is intended to duplicate a common `sed` idiom.

Your expansion, unescaped, ends up replacing “`&amp;`” with itself.

This feature was [added in bash 5.2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061).

Comment: Note that `patsub_replacement` was added in bash v5.2 (see [BashFAQ #61](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061)), so older versions of bash will just treat "&" as literal.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I’ve added that to the answer.